# strpos() stripos() problems php

Tags: php, arrays, strpos, stripos

I know this is a regular question and I'm not trying to join the group of people who don't know that strpos() returns the position of the string, and if you want to compare wether it is found or not you have to use the === or the ==! comparision.

My problem is that, strpos has worked fine everytime, but now it seems to have a problem which I can't find, maybe because I have been looking at it for too long.

My code is like this:

```
$tmp = scandir("img/products");
$productImgs = array();

foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($subCats as $_subItem) {
        $_tmp = $_subItem["SUB_CAT"];
        echo $value." => ".$_tmp."<br>";

        if (strpos(rtrim($value), rtrim($_tmp)) !== FALSE) {
            $productImgs[] = $value;
            echo "lol<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

It basically stores pictures in the **tmp** array then it loops through all the **subCats** array to see if there's a match. For eg.:

```
$_subItem["SUB_CAT"] = "Microplate leolvasók"  
$value = "Microplate leolvasók.jpg"
```

As I echo out all the values there seems to have a match, but it doesn't get added to the array whatsoever.

It prints out this: **Microplate leolvasók.jpg => Microplate leolvasók**

I seem to have found no difference between the two strings apart from the .jpg ending but it shouldn't count because of the function of strpos(). My strings are in utf8 for **$subCats** array, and for **$tmp** array, it is what scandir gives you back. The directory is not protected, it, and the file can be read and written.

Any idea why doesn't it match?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `$subCats` come from?

Comment: use `utf8_encode($haystack), utf8_encode($needle)`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: $subCats come from a mysqli request.

Comment: leolvasók != leolvasók - the `ó` and `ó` are different. With the font you use they may look the same.

Comment: Ah, you might be right! That's why my stripAccents() function didn't work on them. I'll try it out and reply to you if it works. If it does, please post it as an answer so I can accept it! :)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem @Tigger. Please post the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accent on the 'o' in leolvasók != leolvasók. Basically the `ó` and `ó` are different.

With the font you use they may look the same. For me, on Firefox, under Linux there is a slight visual difference.